# JQUERY Get Image title, then put to a element

Tags: jquery

im confused how to put title attribute from "img" element to "a" element.. 
pls, anyone can help me ?

HTML :

```
<div id="product" class="productbox">
<a href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="12345"></a>
<a href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="qwerty"></a>
<a href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="rabbit"></a>
<a href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="kirby"></a>
<a href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="dragon"></a>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
function title_image(){   
var img_title = $(".productbox a img").attr("title");
$(".productbox a").attr("title",img_title);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
title_image();
});
```

Result from the code :

```
<div id="product">
<a title="12345" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="12345"></a>
<a title="12345" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="qwerty"></a>
<a title="12345" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="rabbit"></a>
<a title="12345" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="kirby"></a>
<a title="12345" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="dragon"></a>
</div>
```

I want result like this :

```
<div id="product">
<a title="12345" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="12345"></a>
<a title="qwerty" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="qwerty"></a>
<a title="rabbit" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="rabbit"></a>
<a title="kirby" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="kirby"></a>
<a title="dragon" href="..."><img src="blablabla" title="dragon"></a>
</div>
```

This is the link i write on jsfiddle 
[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/khen/4wzLZ/1/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through each `a` element and then assign the title

```
function title_image() {
    $(".productbox a").attr("title", function(){
        return $(this).find('img').attr('title')
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X23gu/)

Comment: yep thats what i want.. 
What the function of "return" ?
Thank you so musch its works.. :)

Comment: the function returns a value which will be set as teh title of the current `a` element

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the productbox items. Then the $(this) is a reference to the current item so you can get the image title and apply it to the anchor.

```
$(".productbox").each(function() {
  var img_title = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
  $(this).find("a").attr("title",img_title);
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/4wzLZ/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the titles of every link that way.

Try this:

```
function title_image(){   
    $(".productbox a img").each(function(){
        $(this).parent().attr('title', $(this).attr('title'));
    }
});
```

This loops through every img and sets the title of the parent (the a) to the title of the img